# Socket Write Error in Tomcat with Jquery and Rest (Apache CXF)

Tags: jquery, apache, tomcat, websocket, cxf

I am developing an application where i have a login page with username and password.After i provide the credentials i invoke a restful webservice running in tomcat with apache CXF .I get socket write error in apache when response it built.I get the error only for this call whereas other rest endpoints are working fine with successful response.

Code Snippet

```html
<html><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Kovil Registration System</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="pen-title">
  <h1>Kovil Reservation System</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="module form-module">
  
  <div class="form">
   <h2>Admin Login</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="form">
   <h2>Admin Login</h2>
   <form>
    <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username"> 
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button>Login</button>
   </form>
  </div>
  <div class="cta">
   <a>Forgot your password?</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.form-module button').click(function(event) {
  alert("inside submit");
  var kovilRequestDTO={
   "username" : $("input[name=username]").val(),
   "password" : $("input[type='password']").val()
    };
  var data=JSON.stringify(kovilRequestDTO);
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:8091/KovilRestServices/kovilRestService/validateAdmin", 
      data: data,
      timeout: 60000,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
       alert("success");
       window.location.href = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/jsp/success.jsp";
      } 
   });

 });
});
```

Java Backend

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">

<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <jaxrs:server id="base" address="/kovilRestService">
        <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="jsonProvider"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
  <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
        <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
    </jaxrs:extensionMappings> 
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="kovilRestService" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
<bean id="kovilRestService" class="com.kovil.rest.service.KovilRestServiceImpl" />

<bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider"/>
```

```
    public Response validateAdmin(KovilRequestDTO kovilRequestDTO){
    KovilBusinessService kovilBusinessService=loadBusinessBean();
    String username=kovilRequestDTO.getUsername();
    String password=kovilRequestDTO.getPassword();
    KovilResponseObject kovilResponseObject=new KovilResponseObject();
    boolean validationResult=kovilBusinessService.validateAdmin(username, password);
    kovilResponseObject.setSuccessMessage("success");
    return Response.ok(kovilResponseObject).build();
}
```

I am attaching the screenshots recorded where i could see on click of the button i see "Navigated to" message in the console where new URL is formed.Also provided is the snippet of the code and error logs [image: Login Screen][image: Redirection inthe chrome console]

Logs

```
Jan 24, 2016 1:02:05 AM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
 WARNING: Interceptor for   {http://service.rest.kovil.com/}KovilRestServiceImpl has thrown exception,  unwinding now
 org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
at   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:113)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:336)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor.handleMessage(OutgoingChainInterceptor.java:83)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:241)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:206)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:367)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.flushBuffer(Response.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.flushBuffer(ResponseFacade.java:306)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$WrappedOutputStream.close(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:750)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$BackChannelConduit.close(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:679)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
... 35 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:215)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.flush(InternalOutputBuffer.java:119)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:801)
at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:172)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:363)
... 42 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved now. I removed the form tag from my JSP.It was a trial and error but yes it did resolve my issue and i was getting successful response.